# How to import products with price lists, warehouses, locations, vendor,...etc in Odoo 10

Tags: import, export, odoo-10

I have 2 databases. One have some products, warehouses and some related information.

I want export them and import into new database. But I got some errors when import, please check it

```
No matching record found for external id '__export__.product_pricelist_item_7' in field 'Pricelist Items' between rows 2 and 10
Get all possible values
No matching record found for external id '__export__.stock_location_44' in field 'Production Location' between rows 2 and 10
Get all possible values
No matching record found for external id 'l10n_vn.1_tax_purchase_vat10' in field 'Vendor Taxes' between rows 2 and 10
Get all possible values
No matching record found for external id '__export__.stock_location_45' in field 'Inventory Location' between rows 2 and 10
Get all possible values
No matching record found for external id '__export__.product_product_53' in field 'Products' between rows 2 and 10
Get all possible values
No matching record found for external id 'l10n_vn.1_tax_sale_vat10' in field 'Customer Taxes' between rows 2 and 10
Get all possible values
No matching record found for external id '__export__.product_supplierinfo_1' in field 'Vendors' between rows 2 and 10
```

Answer (score 0):

`No matching record found for external id '__export__.product_pricelist_item_7'`

This is saying you don't have a Pricelist Item (line) in the database you're trying to import to. The other errors are related to Inventory Locations, Product Locations, Customer Taxes, Vendor Taxes, and Vendors (on the Product form).

Before you can import what you're trying to import, you must get the related data into the database.

You can do this by separately exporting the data from each appropriate menu or redoing the product export and exporting more data (using the plus icon on fields to drill down further to get those related records' information).

Comment: So if I want to import all products and related data I just expand the child data like child of Priceslists ?
I tried to import after expanded all plus, but still errors "No matching..."

Comment: The safest way is to go to Pricelists tree view directly (Sales > Configuration > Pricelists) to Export them, then import the Pricelists into the other database. After that (and any other dependencies) you can easily import the primary spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. I understand that all dependencies must be imported before the pricelists but I didn't find how to export or import the product pricelist items. Does anyone know?

I'm answering to myself, in case that can help someone; based on version 9 of Odoo here is the list of fields that I use to export from one database to another one:

- Active
- Currency
- Discount Policy
- Pricelist Name
- Pricelist Items/Apply On
- Pricelist Items/Based On
- Pricelist Items/End Date
- Pricelist Items/Fixed Price
- Pricelist Items/Max. Price Margin
- Pricelist Items/Min. Price Margin
- Pricelist Items/Min. Quantity
- Pricelist Items/Percentage Price
- Pricelist Items/Price Discount
- Pricelist Items/Price Rounding
- Pricelist Items/Price Surcharge
- Pricelist Items/Product
- Pricelist Items/Product Category
- Pricelist Items/Product Template
- Pricelist Items/Sequence
- Pricelist Items/Start Date
- Pricelist Items/unknown

When importing the CSV file the "Pricelist Items" are created and the

```
No matching record found for external id __export__.product_pricelist_item_7'
```

error disappears.